# Spring: Mongo configuration can't find "mongo:repositories"

Tags: java, xml, spring, mongodb

I'm with a JEE project, from Maven project to Dynamic Web.
The problem is that I haven't use xml configuration, but now, with the Dynamic web project, I must.

I can't figure out how write right the applicationContext.xml; I've read a lot of topic but no one help me.

Here the code and error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mong‌​o"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

  <!-- Abilita l'uso di tutte le annotazioni -->
  <context:annotation-config/>
  <import resource="security-config.xml"/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="it.**"/>

  <!-- Abilita il supporto AOP -->
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
  <util:properties id="settings" location="classpath:../../META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>

  <!-- i valori delle properties vengono iniettati in AuthentificationFilter e il id=myProps serve per l'iniezione -->
  <util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:muru/application.properties"/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="locations">
   <list>
     <value>classpath*:muru/*.properties</value>
   </list>
 </property>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
  <constructor-arg>
  <bean class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
    <constructor-arg value="localhost"/>
    <constructor-arg value="27017"/>
  </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg value="database"/>
</bean>
 <mongo:repositories base-package="it.cap.domain" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate"></mongo:repositories>
    <!-- Abilita la configurazione delle transazioni tramite annotazioni -->
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
   <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
   </beans>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
11:12:26.108 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 68 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 68; columnNumber: 93; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:repositories'.
at                      org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:repositories'.
```

Can you help me to understand? 
Thanks in advice :)

Comment: well error says that you have error in schema declaration, so you must have schema declaration either in same version or remove the version at all, then maven update and then try to build

Comment: Is in your package `*.domain` any repository?

Comment: @smsnheck Yes.
For FlyingZombie, I'll try to remove the version, anyway I haven't "Maven update" from menu (right click)

Comment: for maven update right click on project>maven>update project>force update snapshot>ok

Comment: @FlyingZombie What I mean is that I haven't "Maven" from that menu :( (maybe because the proj is a Dynamic Web Project?)

Comment: do you have `jars` in build path and then `deployment descriptor/Assembly`?

Comment: Yes, infact I have no problem with import of lib in classes;
about the deployment descriptor/assembly, that config come to me from other, I just set them up as they tell me

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be from the order of the bean definition in your context file.

Just try changing the position of the below bean definition

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

from currrent position to just after the below bean.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.**"/>
```

Something like

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.**"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

See if this solves your issue.

For your reference..
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/9895-order-of-bean-definitions-matters

If the above solution doesn't works ,last thing I guess would be to check if right jars holding the specified mongo related xsds under your application's lib folder

Comment: I am not sure if `xml` is order dependent

Comment: yes its saying that *dependent bean must be initialized first* but I am not sure this has anything to do with question if `depends-on` is not declared then it doesn't matters and I will really like to know how it ends :)

Comment: @mhasan that's not the problem, I still have this: 
    "org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 72 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 72; columnNumber: 93; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:repositories'."

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, in **applicationContext.xml** I just put an import tag to resource "spring.xml":

```
<import resource="spring.xml" />
```

And inside **spring.xml**:

```
<!-- MongoDB host -->
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />

<!-- Template for performing MongoDB operations -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" c:mongo-ref="mongo" c:databaseName="dbname" />

<!-- Activate Spring Data MongoDB repository support -->
<mongo:repositories base-package="it.domain" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />

<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

Now it starts without tomcat's crash; I wil let you know if it works fine with db's connections.